# How can I convert a datetime string to a UNIX timestamp in SQLite3?

Tags: function, datetime, sqlite

[The documentation for SQLite3 datatypes](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) says

> the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values

I want to use those functions to store `INTEGER` values. How do I do so? [The documentation for SQLite3 datetime functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) describes the types of the arguments to those functions, but says nothing of the return type. It seems that the return type is `text`:

```
sqlite> select typeOf(datetime('2014-12-12 12:12:12.000'));
text
```

This is not what I want -- I want an integer value representing that time as a UNIX timestamp. Even when I create a column of type `integer` and attempt to store a `datetime(...)` value in it, SQLite stores it as a `text` value in that `integer` column.

How do I force the `datetime` function and friends to return a UNIX timestamp, instead of a `text` value?

Answer (score 26):

All the built-in date/time functions return strings.

To convert a string into a number, use [CAST](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr):

```
SELECT CAST(strftime('%s', 'now') AS INT);
```

Comment: For mer worked:  `SELECT CAST(strftime('%s', strftime('%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00+00:00', <your_datetime_column>), 'unixepoch') as datetime) FROM  <your_table>`